# Error loading operating system v2v VMDK to vhd

Tags: hyper-v, vhd

I have 2003 vm that works fine in VMware player, using StarWind v2v converter and I get the above error.

I first noticed that the 03 vm needed to be upgraded to a sp2 in order to work with Hyper-V as a minimum, that was compleated with no change, after some searching I found http://www.netexpertise.eu/en/systems/windows/hyper-v-error-loading-operating-system-after-running-disk2vhd.html

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AACp.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFubP.jpg

no partition table found, if that helps

following that lead to the disk ending up raw.

Anyone else had this issue before and willing to share, I do have another method of creating a new VM and migrating the data but that is a last ditch method.

I have tried building the VM in both generation 1 and two.

Comment: I rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate here to edit your question to say [SOLVED] in the title and add the solution to the question. If you've solved the problem and want to share the solution, do so by writing an answer in the space provided below for that purpose; it's perfectly acceptable to [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) here. If you don't want to do that, you have two options: 1) wait for someone else to post an answer, which you can accept as the solution, or 2) delete your question if you don't think the solution will help others.

Comment: I've tried StarWind V2V on Windows Server 2008 a couple of times and it worked nicely. It could be a settings mismatch. Play with different VM settings, try SCSI bus instead of IDE, etc.